# delete odd numbers in a range

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a code which deletes the odd numbers in a user-defined range (for example, between 4 and 10). So far I have this:

```
def even(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return None
    else:
        s = list(range(x, y+1))
        for i in s:
            if s[i]%2!=0:
                del s[i]
                return s

even(4,10)
```

When I run the code, it returns [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10] instead of [4, 6, 8, 10]. Any idea why?

Comment: Use `[i for i in range(x,y+1) if i%2==0]`

Answer (score 2):

It makes little sense to create a larger collection and then remove the items you don't want.

I suspect it would be better if you just create the list with what you want up front:

```
def even(lo, hi):
    if lo > hi: return None # although [] may make more sense
    return [item for item in range(lo, hi + 1) if item % 2 == 0]
```

The reason why I state that it may be better to return `[]` for the case of `lo > hi` is because that's what gets returned for *other* edge cases, such as `even(3,3)`.

This gives what you desire, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> def even(lo, hi):
...     if lo > hi: return None
...     return [item for item in range(lo, hi + 1) if item % 2 == 0]
...
>>> even(4, 10)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things wrong with your code.

1. Using `s[i]` accesses the `i`th item of the list, but `i` is *already* holding the list item because you did `for i in s:`:

   ```
   >>> s = list(range(4, 11))
   >>> s
   [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   >>> for i in s:
   ...   print(i)
   ... 
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
   ```

   What your loop is actually checking with `s[i]` is this:

   ```
   >>> for i in s:
   ...   print(s[i])
   ... 
   8    # i=4, s[4]
   9    # i=5, s[5]
   10   # i=6, s[6]
   ```
2. When you do find an odd number (`s[5]=9`, `9%2 != 0`), you immediately break out of the loop because of the `return s`. So, your loop will only remove the first odd number it finds, then immediately break out of the loop.

   Maybe it's just wrongly indented, but the `return s` should be at the end of the function, not inside the loop.
3. You are removing items from the list while you are iterating over it. That is never a good idea, because that will mess up the loop.

   ```
   >>> s = list(range(4, 11))
   >>> for idx, i in enumerate(s):
   ...   print(i)
   ...   if i%2 != 0:
   ...     print("removing i")
   ...     del s[idx]
   ... 
   4
   5
   removing i
   7  # notice that 6 was now skipped after removing 5
   removing i
   9  # notice that 8 was now skipped after removing 7
   removing i
   ```

With that said, the correct way is to iterate over the input list but the result/output should be on a different list. That way, the loop does not get messed up. The simplest (and most "pythonic") way is by using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def even(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return None
    else:
        s = list(range(x, y+1))
        return [d for d in s if d % 2 == 0]
```

Or, you can manually loop using `while` and then track the correct list index:

```
def even(x,y):
    if x > y:
        return None
    else:
        s = list(range(x, y+1))
        idx = 0
        while idx < len(s):
            if s[idx]%2!=0:
                del s[idx]
                # after this, s[idx] now points to the next item
            else:
                idx += 1
                # move to the next item

    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code. you can remove from list by items and del by index in python:

```
def even(x,y):
 if x > y:
    return None
 else:   
    s = list(range(x, y+1))
    for i in s:
        if i%2 != 0:
            s.remove(i)
    return s
even(4,10)
```